# h5p content type install

Tags: moodle, h5p

In moddle i installed h5p plugin. When i tried to installed content type in console i am getting error and h5p hub disaapear .[image] .Kindly help me

In moddle i installed h5p plugin. When i tried to installed content type in console i am getting error and h5p hub disaapear and i am getting this error : TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'libraries')
in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a compatibility issue with PHP 8 that needs to be fixed by the H5P core team (or patched by yourself). Please refer to https://github.com/h5p/moodle-mod_hvp/pull/472.